# Report prints less records per page when Printing is scheduled

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

When I print a crystal report directly, it prints about 8-9 records per page. However, when I schedule the same report to be printed later, the report prints about 6 records per page.

Note: Currently I am using SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .Net Framework version - 13.0.24.2970.

The tool I am using to design the Crystal Reports rpts: SAP Crystal Reports 2016 Support Pack 3 Version 14.2.3.2132

**Expected Output**: Whether the rpt is printed immediately or is a scheduled print, it should print same number of records in each page.

**Actual Output**: Less number of records are printed when scheduled as compared to when printed immediately.

Comment: Check if in both scenarios the printer settings are the same. For example, maybe when you print directly, the settings belong to the client machine; but when you schedule, the settings belong to the server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the default printer in these 2 scenarios is different (hence, different page size or different default page margins).